# C++ std::regex How to fix the error_complexity?

Tags: regex, c++11

I used `std::regex` to match a string.

My define of regex is :

```
regex reg("(-?\\d+,?){2,}", regex::icase)
```

Test string is :

```
5,3240,7290,11340,-3240,-7290,-11340
```

I used std function of `regex_match()`.
The following is the error I got.

> regex_error(error_complexity): The complexity of an attempted match
>   against a regular expression exceeded a pre-set level.

How can I fix the problem ? My compiler is VS2013.

Comment: You regex can be written as `"[xyz]-?\\d+(?:,[xyz]-?\\d+)+"` but it would not match the string you provided because there are no `x`, `y` or `z`  in it. Maybe you need `"[xyz]?-?\\d+(?:,[xyz]?-?\\d+)+"`?

Comment: Sorry, I have put a wrong regex. It has been modified.

Comment: Again, it contains nested quantifiers where one pattern is obligatory and the other is optional. First, change it to `-?\\d+(?:,-?\\d+)+` and then switch to *Release* mode.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't match the string with a comma at the beginning, just like this(,3240,7290,11340). It reached my purpose. I just want to know why.

Comment: Add `,?` in the beginning.

Comment: Do you mean `-?\\d+(?:,?-?\\d+)+` ?

Comment: See my updated answer. Here is [a demo](https://ideone.com/sjx6j8).

Comment: So, let's see about the previous question. It's about the regex : `[xyz]-?\\d+(?:,[xyz]-?\\d+)+`. I want to match the string `x150,x250,x350`, but not to match `x150,y250,z350`. So, what should the regex to be?

Comment: `x-?\\d+(?:,x-?\\d+)+`, and if you plan to match only identical letters matched at the start, use [`([xyz])-?\\d+(?:,\\1-?\\d+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/hFBcIX/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may "unroll" the `,?`-containing group into a more linear pattern to reduce complexity - `",?-?\\d+(?:,-?\\d+)+"`.

See  [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/vGh1Vf):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    regex reg(",?-?\\d+(?:,-?\\d+)+");
    string s("5,3240,7290,11340,-3240,-7290,-11340");
    if (regex_match(s, reg)) {
        std::cout << "Matched!"; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the pattern matches:

- `,?` - an optional comma
- `-?` - an optional hyphen
- `\\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:,-?\\d+)+` - 1 or more sequences matching

  - `,` - a comma
  - `-?\\d+` - see above.

Comment: I know that. Cause I put the wrong regex. I'm sorry about that. Please see it again. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer to allow matching both `5,3240,7290,11340,-3240,-7290,-11340` and [`,3240,7290,11340`](https://ideone.com/sjx6j8).